# How to change the width of a movieclip in flash html5 canvas?

Tags: createjs, flash-cc, flashcanvas

I was created a new project using flash cc html5 canvas and created a movieclip with 200px width and 200px height. I can able to get the properties using `this.mc.nominalBounds;`. And I tried `this.mc.getBounds ();`
But it returns `null`. `setBounds` also not seems to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `setBounds` method is for putting a custom bounds on something, or defining it when it can not be determined (like using the Graphics classes). Fortunately, all symbols from Flash CC come with `nominalBounds`, which is the combined, untransformed size of the symbol.

Using that, you can set the `scaleX` and `scaleY` properties to size up and down your content. If you want it to be a specific width, just use the nominalBounds to determine a new scale.

For example, if the clip is 200x200, and you want it to be 400x400, then:

```
var scale = newWidth / nominalBounds.width;
clip.scaleX = clip.scaleY = scale;
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Yes..Bounds is similar to rectangle in as3. Thanks for your help.